Best Practice: Acquiring Currency in Taiwan
Apparently it's necessary to have local Taiwanese currency when traveling in Taipei.  Am I better of withdrawing from an ATM or exchanging US dollars inside a bank with a person?    Maybe there is another method? What is the best practice?
Details / Context:

Said link indicates it can be a challenge to find ATMs
I have my debit bankcards, that feature the Visa Logo (BoFA / Truist)
It's 3AM in Taipei.  I used ApplePay for a cab to my hotel.
If it helps assume I'm near: No.87, Lane 155, Dunhua North Rd., Taipei 105, Taiwan

If you have experience in Taipei with the subject matter, please be sure to state this in your answer.   Thank you for any constructive advice / guidance.

I can relate my Korean experience and from different forums, it seems Taiwan is not much different. The good news is that you can find ATM in almost every metro station and  7-Eleven convenient stores (they are open 24/7/365) as one shown in the image and as this Reddit suggests they also accept American cards as well.


Any comments on how to make better decisions / lessons learned are appreciated.

While they may accept American cards, how do they compare in fees?  Because I wouldn't believe that random ATMs like these are the cheapest.

@PeterM if you get a debit card that reimburses ATM fees, you don't need to care :)
